# How to sort an array of dates in descending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdate, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary that parsed to an array one of the element is date, i tried using `[startimeArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];` (starttimeArray) is my date but it only arrange ascending. how can i sort in descending order. thanks

Comment: Could you post more sample code? Perhaps post the `compare:` method.

Comment: i don't have compare method, its very strange that it sort in ascending order, what i read that ascending is the default order in sortUsingSelector. do you have an example of method that can arrange the date in descending order? thank you

Comment: Look at @AKV answer. The `NSSortDescriptor` is what you're looking for. Just set ascending to NO like he did in the answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sort the array by puting **NO** is ascending parameter:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSArray *reverseOrder=[dateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Comment: where will i place this? sorry @AKV i'm new to ios

Comment: The place where you want to sort the array. After sorting the array use this array as datasource of your uitableView.

Comment: you mean the reverseOrder will be my new content?

Answer (score 20):

You can use a comparator block

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(NSDate *d1, NSDate *d2) {
    return [d1 compare:d2];
}];
```

to reverse the order, just swap the dates

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(NSDate *d1, NSDate *d2) {
    return [d2 compare:d1];
}];
```

or — as `compare:` returns a NSComparisonResult, which is actually typedef'ed to integer <sub>see below</sub> — just multiply by -1

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(NSDate *d1, NSDate *d2) {
    return -1* [d1 compare:d2];
}];
```

---

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

Comment: I'd suggest that, for readability's sake, the block be more explicit. Perhaps check if it's `NSOrderedAscending` and set to `NSOrderedDescending` explicitly, and vice versa. Both of the approaches (switching the argument order and multiplying by -1) strike me as depending too much on implementation details and not being clear to future readers.

Comment: i try to understand your solution but i am new in ios and i cannot follow. sorry where will i place this? i load my array from dictionary in viewDidload

Comment: Wehre u u need it. U can just write it to a instanc variable. If u need more help show us all relevant code

Comment: @ikinci viking, In my Array have 50 date objects, in this case how can i compare and sort it?

Comment: @G.Ganesh: just like you would with 2,5 or 5000

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the built-in `reverseObjectEnumerator` method of `NSArray`

```
startimeArray = [startimeArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
startimeArray = [[startimeArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

It's useful when you need the array sorted in ascending and descending order, so you can easily go back to the previous sort.

Answer (score 1):

There is the swift solution for the checked solution :

```
let sortedArray = randomArray.sortedArrayUsingComparator { (d1, d2) -> NSComparisonResult in
    return (d1 as! NSDate).compare(d2 as! NSDate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

For anyone using swift 3.0 this [DateHelper](https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper) will save u some headache.

```
   filteredLogs.sort(by: {
        let firstElement = $0.timeStamp! as Date
        let secondElement = $1.timeStamp! as Date
        return firstElement.compare(.isEarlier(than: secondElement))
    })
```

The above code is a snippet from one of my projects. It uses the helper class to sort my logs with most recent dates at the left of the array. The $ sign is a [positional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258603/what-do-0-1-2-mean-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

In the Class where the Array elements are being initialized.

```
-(NSComparisonResult) compareArray: (id) element {
    Return [ArrayElement compare: [element ArrayElement]];
}



-(NSComparisonResult) compareArrayReverse: (id) element {
    Return [[element ArrayElement] compare: ArrayElement];
}
```

Then in the Class where your startimeArray is initialized:

```
@synthesize ArrayName;


-(void) sort: (BOOL) sel {
    if (sel) {
        [ArrayName sortUsingSelector: @selector(compareArray:)];
    } else {
        [ArrayName sortUsingSelector: @selector(compareArrayReverse:)];
    }    
}
```

Then in the main():

```
// Sort the array. sort = TRUE - ascending order, sort = FALSE - descending order.

[startimeArray sort: FALSE];
```