# Bash script - File directory does not exist

Tags: bash

I'm creating a very simple bash script that will check to see if the directory exists, and if it doesn't, create one.

However, no matter what directory I put in it doesn't find it!

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
$1="/media/student/System"

if [ ! -d $1 ]
then

    mkdir $1
fi
```

Here is the command line error:

```
./test1.sh: line 2: =/media/student/System: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your script stops before the `if` test. Your allocation is wrong.

Comment: Why do you use `$1`? This is a special variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258603/what-do-0-1-2-mean-in-shell-script

Comment: the correct way to do what you want would be : `my_var="/media/student/System"; if[ ! -d $my_var] ....`

Comment: You could have it even easier with paramater p to the mkdir command

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="/media/student/System"

if [ ! -d "${directory}" ]
then
    mkdir "${directory}"
fi
```

or even shorter with the `parent` argument of mkdir ([manpage of mkdir](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir))

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="/media/student/System"
mkdir -p "${directory}"
```

Comment: Though it's not a problem in this example with this particular hard coded string, it's probably still better to always quote your variables

Answer (score 3):

In bash you are not allow to start a variable with a number or a symbol except for an underscore `_`. In your code you used `$1` , what you did there was trying to assign `"/media/student/System"` to `$1`, i think maybe you misunderstood how arguments in bash work. I think this is what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
directory="$1" # you have to quote to avoid white space splitting

if [[ ! -d "${directory}" ]];then
     mkdir "$directory"
fi
```

run the script like this

```
$ chmod +x create_dir.sh
$ ./create_dir.sh "/media/student/System"
```

What the piece of code does is to check if the "/media/student/System" is a directory, if it is not a directory it creates the directory