# Pass java main methods arguments from shell script input

Tags: java, shell, sh, command-line-arguments

I have implemented a chat server client. I have written the following shell script to dynamically take in the server port number: server.sh

> javac -classpath . com/chat/ChatConstants.java
>
> javac -classpath . com/chat/ChatServer.java
>
> echo Enter server port number
>
> read $1
>
> java com.chat.ChatServer $1

This is the java main method I am trying to pass the argument to :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // The default port number.
    int portNumber = 8888;
    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("Chat server is up on " + portNumber);
    } else {
        portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
        System.out.println("Chat server is up on " + portNumber);
    }
   }
```

However, the port number printed is always the default port ie 8888. When I run the java program as follows

> java com.chat.ChatServer 2727

The cmd line args are taken properly and server port is set to 2727.

I seem to be doing something wrong in the shell script. I even tried passing the arguments with quotes as follows:

> java com.chat.ChatServer "$1"

The command prompt closes promptly.

Please help

Comment: Don't name your variable `$1`. That already has a meaning in shell.

Comment: the line read $1 is unnecessary in theory, the $1 refers to the first argument by [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258603/what-do-0-1-2-mean-in-shell-script/29258644).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should be:

```
read PORT
java com.chat.ChatServer $PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

`$1` is a special variable which holds the first commandline argument passed to the shell script.

You need to `read` your input into a different variable.

**Edit:**
Just a sidenote, you can print a prompt without using `echo` by using `read -p "Enter server port number" P`.