# Stat function in shell scripting centos

Tags: shell

Not able to get my head around the below function. Please somebody explain in simple way?

```
Stat() {
if [ "$1" = "SKIP" ]; then 
    echo -e " > $2 - \e[35mSKIPPING\e[0m"
elif [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo -e " > $2 - \e[32mSUCCESS\e[0m"
else
    echo -e " > $2 - \e[33mFAILURE\e[0m"
    echo Refer $LOG file for errors
    exit 1
fi 
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258603/what-do-0-1-2-mean-in-shell-script

Comment: Depends what are you not understanding. The function receive 2 arguments, if the first is 0 print's success, if it's SKIP it prints skipping, if it's anything else it prints Failure. That's about it.