# How many arguments are passed to the command by the shell:

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find out how many arguments are passed to the command by the shell:

```
echo "It's "'funny how'" it's done."
```

It is 1 argument, because first ' turn off the " after s , and the ' after turn off following " , so first " matches the last ".

For

```
"<bar bar -b "-a" '-r' >bar bar bar"
```

I don't understand why 5 argument are passed to the command by shell

pig pig pig

[image]

```
6   arguments passed to command by shell
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5163144/608639), [What do $? $0 $1 $2 mean in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29258603/608639) and friends.

Comment: Also see [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: You say "I don't understand why 5 argument are passed to the command", then you show "6   arguments passed to command by shell". Why do you say 5 but show 6?

Comment: not the dfference between `set -- "It's "'funny how'" it's done."; echo $# ; set -- "It's " 'funny how' " it's done." ; echo $#`. ($# is the number of arguments visible to the shell, `set --` puts whatever follows as the arguments to the current shell process, so you can also do `echo $3` for instance. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Bash converts its input to tokens based on the sequence

- Quoting
- Expansion (brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic  expansion, **word splitting**, and pathname expansion)

Applying the above to the: `echo "It's "'funny how'" it's done."`:

1. de-quoting will result in 3 replacements ('*' indicate quoted space)

   1. double quoted `It's*`
   2. Single quoted `funny*how`
   3. Single quoted `*it's*done.`
2. The word splitting looks for unquoted spaces to separate into arguments. Given no (unquoted) spaces, all the above are combined into one argument. `It's*funny*how*it's*done.`

Note that quoting are not nested, as implied by the question (e.g., single quote within double quotes does NOT have special meaning).

Following on `<pig pig -x " " -z -r" " >pig pig pig` ('*' is quoted space, '_' is unquoted space).

1. de-quoting will result in 2 replacements ('*' indicate quoted space)

   1. Unquoted `<pig_pig_-x_`
      2, Double quoted `*`
   2. Unquoted `_-z_-r`
   3. Double quoted `*`
   4. Unquoted '_>pig_pig_pig`
2. Word splitting will process the combined `<pig_pig_-x_*_-z_-r*_>pig_pig_pig`. Splitting on **unquoted**  spaces: "pig", "pig", "pig". The 'pig' will be processed by the shell: redirect input and output. Resulting in 7 parameter.