# Getting blank output while CMD & ENTRYPOINT instructions together

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, docker-entrypoint

My `dockerfile` looks as below:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT echo
CMD ["helloworld"]
```

The container built from the above dockerfile image is giving a blank output.

```
[root@dockerhost dproj]# docker run -it --name con1 demo

[root@dockerhost dproj]#
```

Expected Output:
`helloworld`

Comment: `The container built` Soooo did you run it? `Expected Output: echo helloworld` Why should `echo` be in the output?

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint :

> The shell form:
> ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2
>
> The shell form prevents any CMD or run command line arguments from being used, but has the disadvantage that your ENTRYPOINT will be started as a subcommand of /bin/sh -c

From `man sh`:

```
   -c        Read  commands  from the command_string operand. Set the value of special parameter 0 (see Section 2.5.2, Special Parameters) from the
             value of the command_name operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, and so on) in sequence from the remaining argument  operands.
             No commands shall be read from the standard input.
```

`/bin/sh -c echo helloworld` should assign `helloworld` to *shells* `$0` and execute `echo`, which will output an empty line.

I.e. `ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]` is not `ENTRYPOINT echo`.

Comment: can you please help me understand what is meant by ` _shells_ `$0`?`

Comment: `/bin/sh` processes. `/bin/sh` is the shell. I.e. `/bin/sh -c 'echo $0' this_is_the_zero_arg`.

Comment: actually, I am not able to understand what is meant by `/bin/sh processes?` thanks for all the details provided so far. Basically need help with understanding "`/bin/sh -c echo helloworld` should assign `helloworld` to _shells_ `$0` and execute `echo`."

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144514/add-arguments-to-bash-c https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152391/bash-c-with-positional-parameters https://linuxhint.com/0-bash-script/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412707/why-0-is-not-a-positional-parameter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258603/what-do-0-1-2-mean-in-shell-script

Comment: @meallhour In `sh -c "echo" helloworld`, only the thing _directly after `-c`_ -- in this case, the `echo` -- is a script to run. It would need to be `sh -c 'echo helloworld'` for the `helloworld` to be part of that script. Instead, it goes into the argument vector, but the command `echo` doesn't _look_ at the calling shell's argument vector.

Comment: @meallhour, Docker and many other programs (including common versions of `ps`!) confuse this point when they don't add quoting to show how arguments are (or aren't) held together when printing command lines, but what KamilCuk and I are telling you is what happens under the hood; you can look at `/proc/*/cmdline` files with a tool that prints NUL characters, so you can distinguish where there's a NUL and where there's a regular space. (When it's `sh<NUL>-c<NUL>echo hello<NUL>` you get `hello` on output, when it's `sh<NUL>-c<NUL>echo<NUL>hello<NUL>` you don't).